# Can't Edit Frames in Dope Sheet

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I'm trying to create an animation using a linked rig. I created Library Overrides for the rig - I assume this is part of my issue - and I can create key frames, but I cannot modify them in anyway. I don't know why these elements are greyed, either.

Appreciate the help here.
[image]

**UPDATE:** If I view in the Graph Editor, and try to delete a key I get the message "Disabled: there is no animation data to operate on"

[image]

Comment: Did you ever work out a fix for this? My exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure there are no animation keys on your linked rig.
Clear any animation - link in.